# What are simple but efficient parallel loops in Microsoft visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, c++17

I am writing a numerical program using C++, I need to run some lines of my code in parallel. Also, I need to lock some parameters during calculation to keep them safe from unwanted changes.
I do not have a strong background in Concurrency and parallelism.
I need to know what is the simplest parallelization method in Microsoft VS 2019 considering these requirements?
I am looking forward MS solutions and of course I am not mean Open MPI.

It helps more if you provide some examples.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into use of /Qpar flag for compiler and  `#pragma loop`. There is online documentation on that.

Comment: Thanks dear Swift, Dose /Qpar has some attributes like .lock() and .unlock?

Comment: no, it activates  compile-time auto-parallelizer. It's nothing to do with mutual exclusion of any sort, parallelization supposed be a non-racing code , you mistake it it with concurrent execution if you require locks